# How to check the text found on an object in OnTriggerEnter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collider

I have a question, I created a game where I need to collect a Ballon, and check the number of the text that I attached on it:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n90KF.png)

```
  public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Ballon")
        {
       //now I want to check the text//
        }
     }
```

Comment: Just get the text component of other.gameObject and then access the text variable. Then convert this string to an integer.

Comment: Can you please explain to me how?

Comment: I am currently in work, ill explain to you in 2 hours, ok?

Comment: Sure no problem, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very simple to do. As your example you have a `TextMeshPro` in the child of the `other` object. Now in this situation there are two way for you to get the child object.

I'll Add reference links at the bottom of the answer.

1. other.transform.Find();
2. other.transform.GetChild();

### 1. other.transform.Find()

Using `transform.find()` method it will go through all the Game Objects that are child of the the parent object in your case this method will go through all the children of `other` object, as ass soon as it finds the object which matches the name it will return that object.

**Here is an example:**

```
public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Ballon")
    {
         TextMeshPro tmp = other.transform.Find("Text (TMP) (1)").GetComponent<TextMeshPro>();
         if(tmp.text == "text of your liking")
         {
             Debug.Log("Do what you want");
         }
    }
 }
```

### 2. other.transform.GetChild()

This method will directly return the child from the index that you enter. And this method is quit an efficient one to use.

**Here is the example:**

```
public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Ballon")
    {
         TextMeshPro tmp = other.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<TextMeshPro>();
         if(tmp.text == "text of your liking")
         {
             Debug.Log("Do what you want");
         }
    }
 }
```

**References:**

1.[Transform.Find()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Find.html)
2.[Transform.GetChild()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.GetChild.html)

Comment: Don't thank just answer someone else's question

Comment: You could also simply use `GetComponentInChildren<TextMeshPro>()`

Comment: @derHugo Yes, that's right but it can create confusion if there are more then one ```TextMeshPro```.